# Updating a JQuery Tablesorter Filter Function

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, tablesorter

I am using JQuery Tablesorter, latest version, with the Filter widget applied. On two columns, I am using a filter function to display a drop-down in the filter allowing the user to select from all available values.

```
        widgetOptions: {
            filter_functions: {
                3: true,
                4: true
            }
        }
```

When the page loads, and the table is initially populated, these functions work correctly. A drop-down is created for each of my two columns, and it contains all values. Selecting a value properly filters on that value.

However, my problem comes when new rows are dynamically added to the table as the page runs. The values in the drop-down menu do not refresh, when new rows are added that contain new values. Triggering 'update', 'change', etc does not seem to work.

Is there a way to dynamically update this standard filter function when new rows are added to the table during runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, this appears to be a problem with the filter widget. I've fixed it and [updated the tablesorter repository](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/) (now v2.7.2)

[Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/187/) showing it working now :)

Thanks for reporting this issue!

Note: I couldn't submit this answer without any code, so this is how you should update the table:

```
$('table')
    .find('tbody').append(newRow)
    .trigger('update');
```

Comment: Thanks, Mottie! Your super fast response is very much appreciated!

Comment: I got the latest and this solution works. However, a new problem is introduced with this code: The select gets updated when new data gets updated, however, if an option was selected by the user, when the select gets repopulated, that users selection is not saved. For example, in your Fiddle - click "Bruce" then click "Add Row". The option for "Bruce" is reset and the table refreshes.

Comment: To update: I fixed the above problem. In buildSelect() I just grab the value, if present, and store it until the select is rebuilt. If there was a value, then I repopulate it at the end.

Comment: @PatrickD can you provide an example of how you got the value in the buildSelect, I am having the same problem.

Comment: @digitalbart This code may be fixed in Mottie's latest version, but going back, here's what I did. In the beginning of buildSelect(), set a var to the current selection. `var currentSelection = $t.find('thead').find('select.' + css + '[data-column="' + i + '"]')[0].value;` At the end of the buildSelect() method, you can say `$t.find('thead').find('select.' + css + '[data-column="' + i + '"]')[0].value = currentSelection;`

Comment: The resetting of the `select` was killing me! Thank you @PatrickD for this solution; it fixed my issue!!